Usage of פגרים in Parashat Lech-Lecha
In the Brit bein haBetarim (the sixth 'aliyah in Lech-Lecha), the following verse (Gen. 15:11) occurs, with a mystifying uncommon word.

וַיֵּ֥רֶד הָעַ֖יִט עַל־הַפְּגָרִ֑ים וַיַּשֵּׁ֥ב אֹתָ֖ם אַבְרָֽם׃
And the bird of pray fell upon the carcasses and Avram shooed them away.

The word פגר ("carcass", "corpse") rarely occurs in Chumash, the only other time which comes to mind being in Parashat Shelach, where Hashem curses the Dor HaMidbar to die in the dessert. As such, it's a somewhat mystifying usage here, since in no other place is it used to refer to an offering to Hashem.
I checked the commentaries to which I had access* and no one among them addresses the choice of word.
Do any traditional sources address the usage of the word פגר in this context, as opposed to another word ?

*I had access to a Torat Chaim, which includes R' Saadia's Tafsir (translated into Hebrew), Rashi, Ibn 'Ezra, Rashbam, Chizkuni, and Ramba"n. I may have forgotten someone

Why do you assume that the animals here are to be viewed as "offerings to Hashem"?

@JoelK, Hashem commanded Avra(ha)m to prepare the animals as he did, therefore, while it isn't a korban, per se (though it does end up being burnt) it is nonetheless an offering done at haKadosh Baruch Hu's behest

Bereishis Rabbah 44:16:

אָמַר רַבִּי עֲזַרְיָה לִכְשֶׁיֵּעָשׂוּ בָנֶיךָ פְּגָרִים בְּלֹא גִּידִים וַעֲצָמוֹת, זְכוּתְךָ עוֹמֶדֶת לָהֶן
Said R. Azariah: [G-d was telling Avraham,] "When your children will become carcasses, lacking sinews and bones (without any mitzvos or merits - Matnos Kehunah; without any strength or rescue - Etz Yosef), your merit will stand them in good stead."


There are 22 usages of the word פגר in Tanach in the meaning "dead bodies or carcasses" according to the Concordance by Abraham Even-Shoshan. A total of 5 can be found in the Torah, in addition to your examples also Bamidbar 14:29, 14:32, and 14:33 when the punishment for believing the report of the spies was announced.
According to the Etymological Dictionary of Biblical Hebrew by R. Matityhu Clark, the root פגר has meaning abandon, divorce from active life. In addition to the meaning "corpse, carcass", it is also used as "being sluggish" i.e. not so lively (Shmuel A 30:10, 30:21).
